ASP .NET Core Session Values are not preserved
This one is complicated. I have a following middleware in my Program.cs:
app.UseMiddleware<LowercaseUrlMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseWebOptimizer();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseRequestLocalization();localization
app.UseSession();
app.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>();//THIS!!!!
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
app.Run();

Notice SessionMiddleware. That's where problems arise.
Code of SessionMiddleware:
namespace CCUI.Middleware
{
    public class SessionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SessionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var excludedExtensions = new[] { ".css", ".js", ".png", ".jpg", ".gif" };
            var pathValue = context.Request.Path.Value?.ToLower();
            var queryValue = context.Request.QueryString.Value;
            var isAjaxRequest = false;//context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"].ToString().Contains("application/json");
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryValue) || !queryValue.Contains("handler=")) && !isAjaxRequest &&
                (pathValue == null || !excludedExtensions.Any(ext => pathValue.EndsWith(ext))))
            {
                Guid parsedGuid;

                // Checking for the VisitorGUID cookie
                if (!context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("CustomClosetsVisitorGUID", out var visitorGuid) ||
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(visitorGuid) ||
                    !Guid.TryParse(visitorGuid, out parsedGuid))
                {
                    // Generate a new GUID
                    visitorGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                }

                // Set (or reset) the cookie with the GUID value and extend its expiration
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("CustomClosetsVisitorGUID", visitorGuid);

                // Store the VisitorGUID in the session -- this line causes problems
                context.Session.SetString("VisitorGUID", visitorGuid);
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

Notice var isAjaxRequest = false -- this is for testing.
When isAjaxRequest set correctly -- all good. If not, then IN OTHER PARTS of code that read/set session session does not get set. We have /get-cart endpoint in CartController that sets cart guid to session. But after reload it is not set.
It looks like because of concurrency session values are not getting persisted. I read that session is set on request end, so maybe that get obrupted.
So I ajax requests are filtered out in this middleware, then AJAX request to /get-cart works correctly and value persists.... Thoughts?
namespace CCUI.Controllers;
[ApiController]
[Route("api/shopping-cart")]
public class CartController(IShoppingCartService _cartService, ISearchService _searchService, IProductsService _productService, AppConfiguration _appConfig) : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("cart")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetShoppingCart()
    {
        ShoppingCart? cart = null;

        String? guid = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ShoppingCartGuid");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guid))
        { 
            cart = await _cartService.GetShoppingCartByGUIDAsync(guid); 
        }

        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = await _cartService.CreateNewShoppingCartAsync(_appConfig.SalesChannelId, null);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("ShoppingCartGuid", cart.Guid.ToString());
            
        }

        return Ok(cart);
    }

}




Do you mean if you set the isAjaxRequest = false , then you find all the session value is not persisted(you couldn't get it from controller)? But if you set the  isAjaxRequest = true, then you could get the set session value inside the controller?

@BrandoZhang hmmm... not sure. if isAjaxRequest = false, then i GET ShoppingCartGuid - it is null, i create new one, set to session, reload the page, it is null again... Now when you ask I am not sure - the Set does not work, or the Get.
